# Do Sleeping Threads Hold Memory

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, memory

We are having memory pressure issues (`RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE` waits) on one of our servers but there are very few active connections going on at one time. Logically, it wouldn't seem like sleeping connections would hold on to memory but I'm wondering if they actually do?  IderaDM shows several sleeping connections with high Memory Usage.

This is a SQL 2008 SP3 server with 27 Gb of memory.  There's typically only two to 10 active calls going on at any one moment and a good portion of them are having resource_semaphore waits.  This server holds our third party DBs so we can't change most of the calls/procs.

So, is it possible that sleeping connections are holding onto memory or should I be looking elsewhere?

Comment: TeamCity connections were the ones sleeping that appeared to be holding onto the memory.  They restarted the TeamCity service and 18 Gb freed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to track down memory usage and what queries are the biggest offenders, run through the following steps:

1. Identify what DB on the instance is consuming the most memory

   ```
   -- DB using most cache
   DECLARE @total_buffer INT
   SELECT @total_buffer = cntr_value
      FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
      WHERE RTRIM([object_name]) LIKE '%Buffer Manager'
      AND counter_name IN ('Total Pages', 'Database Pages');

   WITH src AS
   (
      SELECT
          database_id, db_buffer_pages = COUNT_BIG(*)
          FROM sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors
          --WHERE database_id BETWEEN 5 AND 32766
          GROUP BY database_id
   )
   SELECT
      [db_name] = CASE [database_id] WHEN 32767
          THEN 'Resource DB'
          ELSE DB_NAME([database_id]) END,
      db_buffer_pages,
      db_buffer_MB = db_buffer_pages / 128,
      db_buffer_percent = CONVERT(DECIMAL(6,3),
          db_buffer_pages * 100.0 / @total_buffer)
   FROM src
   ORDER BY db_buffer_MB DESC;
   ```
2. Dig into what objects within said db are consuming the most memory

   ```
   --objects in DB using most space
   USE DatabaseName
   GO
   WITH src AS
   (
       SELECT
           [Object] = o.name,
           [Type] = o.type_desc,
           [Index] = COALESCE(i.name, ''),
           [Index_Type] = i.type_desc,
           p.[object_id],
           p.index_id,
           au.allocation_unit_id
       FROM
           sys.partitions AS p
       INNER JOIN
           sys.allocation_units AS au
           ON p.hobt_id = au.container_id
       INNER JOIN
           sys.objects AS o
           ON p.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
       INNER JOIN
           sys.indexes AS i
           ON o.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
           AND p.index_id = i.index_id
       WHERE
           au.[type] IN (1,2,3)
           AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0
   )
   SELECT
       src.[Object],
       src.[Type],
       src.[Index],
       src.Index_Type,
       buffer_pages = COUNT_BIG(b.page_id),
       buffer_mb = COUNT_BIG(b.page_id) / 128
   FROM
       src
   INNER JOIN
       sys.dm_os_buffer_descriptors AS b
       ON src.allocation_unit_id = b.allocation_unit_id
   WHERE
       b.database_id = DB_ID()
   GROUP BY
       src.[Object],
       src.[Type],
       src.[Index],
       src.Index_Type
   ORDER BY
       buffer_pages DESC;
   ```
3. Review what queries are hitting said objects in memory

   ```
   USE DatabaseName
   GO

   SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 
           s.total_logical_reads / s.execution_count
       , SUBSTRING(t.TEXT, (s.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1, (
               (
                   CASE s.statement_end_offset
                       WHEN - 1
                           THEN DATALENGTH(t.TEXT)
                       ELSE s.statement_end_offset
                       END - s.statement_start_offset
                   ) / 2
               ) + 1) AS statement_text
       , s.execution_count AS ExecutionCount
       , s.max_elapsed_time AS MaxElapsedTime
       , ISNULL(s.total_elapsed_time / s.execution_count, 0) AS AvgElapsedTime
       , s.creation_time AS LogCreatedOn
       , *
   FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.sql_handle) t
   WHERE TEXT LIKE '%ObjectName_From_QueryAbove%'
       AND TEXT NOT LIKE '%sys.dm_exec_query_stats s%'
   ORDER BY s.total_logical_reads / s.execution_count DESC
   ```

Hopefully this gives you some troublesome queries.  You may find that you just don't have the proper amount of memory in the instance for the workload it's trying to accommodate.  Alternatively you may find a query written by a user missing something as simply infuriating as a predicate (e.g. the `WHERE` clause).

If you want to dig into the execution plan, you can take the `plan_handle` and send it into this query:

```
SELECT query_plan 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_plan (PLAN_HANDLE_FROM_Query_3)
```

and review the execution plan.  If you are not able to tune said query, this probably isn't as useful to you.

Once you figure out what's using the memory on the instance, you can come up with a better idea on how to get the system back to a healthy state.

Answer (score 1):

I use the below query with nothing excluded because I want to see where the SQL Server background waits are and they will all be at the same percentage.  Items like `HADR_FILESTREAM_IOMGR_IOCOMPLETION`, `XE_TIMER_EVENT`, and `REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH`.  If your `RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE` is below the system background stuff then you don't have a problem.  If it is above the system background stuff, then post what it is.

```
SELECT TOP 20 'Waits' as Waits
  ,GETDATE() AS check_time
  ,[Wait type] = wait_type
  ,[Wait time (s)] = wait_time_ms / 1000
  ,[% waiting] = CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,2), wait_time_ms * 100.0 / SUM(wait_time_ms) OVER())
  ,waiting_tasks_count
FROM sys.dm_os_wait_stats
ORDER BY wait_time_ms DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

**RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE** means you have queries that are waiting for a memory grant.

I would query

```
 sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants
```

to see what is using up all of your query workspace memory, and what is waiting for memory.  [This article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2827/troubleshooting-sql-server-resourcesemaphore-waittype-memory-issues/)  gives some good tips for troubleshooting **RESOURCE_SEMAPHORE** issues.  Unfortunately, it typically means you need to tune a query or queries, so if it is 3rd Party code, you may have to go back to the vendor.  Depending on the specific issue, you may be able to improve it by adding an index, but that is just speculation.